# Create EML file MethodInfo.Invoke giving Parameter count mismatch

Tags: c#

I am trying to create .eml file . I use below code. But whenever it reaches to method.Invoke it gives me error **Parameter count mismatch.**.Below is my code to create eml file.

```
    try
        {
           MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
           m.Body = htmlbody;
           var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(m.Body, null, "text/html");

            MailAddress newFromAddress = new MailAddress("select.sender@sender.com", "(Please select sender)");
            m.Sender = null;
            m.From = newFromAddress;
            m.Headers.Add("X-Unsent", "1");  //Make the eml file open in compose mode
            m.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);  //Add the html content to the email
            m.Subject = subject;
            m.IsBodyHtml = true;

            var assembly = typeof(SmtpClient).Assembly;
            var mailWriterType = assembly.GetType("System.Net.Mail.MailWriter");
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                //Construct the mail message file .eml
                ConstructorInfo mailWriterContructor = mailWriterType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { typeof(Stream) }, null);
                object mailWriter = mailWriterContructor.Invoke(new object[] { stream });
                MethodInfo sendMethod = typeof(MailMessage).GetMethod("Send", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
                ///**This is line where I get error**///  sendMethod.Invoke(m, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { mailWriter, true, true }, null);  

                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
```

**UPDATE :**
I am using .Net Framework 2.0. Is this making issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the source it seems Send method only takes 2 arguments

```
 internal void Send(BaseWriter writer, bool sendEnvelope)
```

http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/fx/src/Net/System/Net/Mail/MailMessage@cs/2/MailMessage@cs

You will need to pass these into the invoke call.

```
sendMethod.Invoke(m, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, new[] { mailWriter, true}, null);
```